# ASP.Net Form Application Redirect to Default for all PostBacks

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, url, iis, compatibility

This one's driving me nuts.  I have a .Net Web Form app, not MVC.  Works fine on localhost, also on a development server running server 2012, as an IP address it works fine on a UAT Server running 2012; but with a URL that is assigned to the same IP address for UAT it redirects to the default.aspx with each postback.  Looking in IE, it shows same security level - Intranet, which forces Compatibility using F12 that compatibility shows as ie7 (I'm on IE11), plus everything else looks right in the IE settings.  Trying from another PC with a different user, same results IP works, URL doesn't, and all IE settings appear to be the same.  Fun thing, Chrome works fine with both URL and IP; but IETab in Chrome has the same issue (running as ie7 or ie11).  Anything similar to this out on the Forums just say check Compatibility; which I've done.  I can only assume something is weird with the URL or IIS not recognizing the URL for postback; but I don't understand what or why.

Answer (score 0):

In the IE Tools menu select Compatibility View Settings.  Then uncheck *Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View*.  For the life of me I don't know why that is the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  However, it turned out to be an Under Score in the URL.  For some reason the Under Score caused the Session Cookie in the Post Back to be dropped.  This was only true of Internet Explorer; all other browsers still included the Session Cookie.  i.e. Dummy_URL would cause the issue but DummyURL would fix it.